# Select value from selectbox in the same page

Tags: php, select

When I open my page, $d = " " and when I select a value from selectbox, should $d = selected value.
How can I set $d = selected value When I click on the button?

```
<?php
if ($rows['plus'] < $Stime OR $rows['plus'] == 0) {
    $saveal = mysql_query("UPDATE `".TB_PREFIX."users` SET plus = 0 WHERE id = \"".$userid."\"");
    echo "<b>غير مفعّل</b> ";
    $activ = array('يوم','يومان','3 أيام','4 أيام','5 أيام','6 أيام','7 أيام');
?> 
    <select name="select_day"><option value="" >---</option>
<?php
        foreach($activ as $key => $value):
        echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>'; //close your tags!!
        endforeach;

        ?>
    </select>

<?php

} elseif ($rows['plus'] > 0) {
    echo "<b>مفعّل</b>";
}
?>
<input type="submit" name="activ_plus" value="تفعيل" onclick="<?php
            if ($_POST['select_day'] = "يوم") {
                $d = 6644555;
                $saveal2 = mysql_query("UPDATE `".TB_PREFIX."users` SET plus = \"".$d."\" WHERE id = \"".$userid."\"");
            }
?>">
```

Comment: there are some serious mistakes you made. you cant put php code in javascript

Comment: How is that? I did not understand what you mean.

Comment: onclick="<?php  ... this is totally wrong

Comment: apart from that `=` is not a comparison (in `if ($_POST['select_day'] = "يوم")`)

Comment: where does `$_POST['select_day']` come from? please show whole code. Are you ever sending this form?

Comment: I want an answer, if you can edit the code please.

Comment: it is the name of selectbox @Jeff

Comment: Sure, you want an answer. But 1st we are not your slaves, 2nd there is not enough code to somehow figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: One thing I can say is, that if you don't send your form, $_POST['select_day'] will be empty (with error undefined index)

Comment: I had set <form action="" method="post">

Comment: checkout @mboyde's answer if it heps. I'm out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, this would be much easier to accomplish through Javascript or jQuery. For example, in jQuery, a thing that you could do is:

```
$('#selectBox').change(function(){
var selectValue = $('#selectBox').val();
if(selectValue == 'stringText'){
    $('#textBox').val('something');
}
});
```

This is simply a very routine function/idea that you can use in jQuery.
If the page loads a value for the select box (ex: somthing retrieved from the database) then you can use php through the $rows['selectValue'] from a query to load a certain value in other form fields.
If you are trying to submit the form through "onClick", you need to stop writing new code and read up on either AJAX OR the proper way to submit data using php.

Comment: Can you explain more? I am a beginner

Comment: What are you confused about?

Comment: I don't know how to make javascript. I just want when I select a value from selectbox and click on button, then $d = selected value.

Comment: Or when I select a value fex. $key = 0, then $d = $key + 1.

Comment: So, include the following lines in your <head> section.
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

After the fields that you want to add, place a beginning/ending script tag . Within the script tags, you should be able to use jQuery like the function above.

Comment: You could use a call to a function within the script tag. Example:
1. In your <select> box add:
    onchange = "changeD();"
2. Within the script, write:
    function changeD(){
        selectValue = $('#selectID').val();
        if(selectValue == 'stringText'){
            $('#textBoxID').val('something based on the value of select');
        }
        return false;
    }